# Call to undefined function recode_string() ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7.2

I got the error
Call to undefined function recode_string()

in a simple php script, that had worked seamlessly beforehand.

Manually installing gnu recode on the system would not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install php-recode**

Installing php-recode package on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) is as easy as running the following command on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-recode
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out php-reccode had to be installed manually now while it was formerly included so

```
sudo apt install php-recode
```

fixed it.
Did not find a solution here or in the php manual as yet so thought it might help you too.